# Resellers and web admins and email privacy

Tags: email, privacy, gmail

Maybe I'm missing something, but this is "my problem".

If you ask some company to create some domain for you and several e-mail account with that domain and forward that information to your gmail account.

How do you forbids that the developer company/reseller can check all your mails?

Practical example: I create employee@mycompany.com at godaddy.com.

I can always check all the mail from that employee.

Is there any way to work this out?

I do not really understand, ANY web developer can check all mails from any client, or Am I missing someting?

Answer (score 3):

> If you ask some company to create some domain for you and several e-mail account with that domain and forward that information to your gmail account...I do not really understand, ANY web developer can check all mails from any client, or Am I missing someting?

In a way your question is funny: you fear that the domain provider might intercept and read your mail when it gets forwarded to your gmail account but you don't fear that somebody is reading the mail at the forwarded account itself, i.e. the mails which are stored at google's servers outside of your control. The mail can be read in both cases and it will at least be done if these providers get a warrant because law enforcement needs to get access to information in thus mails.

If you make decisions to give somebody else such level of control over your data you have to ask yourself how much you trust this company. This is the same question you have to ask yourself with your telecom provider, because both land lines and mobile calls can be intercepted by the provider and this will be done if law enforcement requires it. And the same is true with your internet access.

Thus in your specific case you need to trust google to not read your mails or at least don't use any information in these mails against you. And you have to trust your domain provider to not read the mails when forwarding and also to set up the interface for forwarding in a way which can not be hacked by someone - because then the mail could get just be intercepted some yet another party. And there is probably more trust involved.

> How do you forbids that the developer company/reseller can check all your mails?

The only way to be sure that no third party is reading your mails is to encrypt them. This does not mean TLS which does only hop-by-hop encryption between mail servers but the mail is available in plain text at the mail server itself. Instead you need to use end-to-end encryption like PGP or S/MIME. But of course end-to-end only works if sender and recipient use this kind of encryption. And meta data like sender, recipient, time and size of the mail are still visible even if the mail content itself is encrypted.

Comment: I believe due my lack of native English, the question was quite NOT well understood.
I do not care if the NSA, USA, GMAIL, MicroSoft,goDaddy or my ISP is reading my mails.

It is much more simple, Im having this issue with MY clients.
We just enter in the web development service and a lot of companies ask you to create them some domain to their companies. And associate to some new emails for them to their gmails

It does not matter how "professional" we are, and "trust" they have in us, WE SHOULD NOT HAVE the ability to check their mails!!!

And this is the case always or Im missing something?

Comment: @voskyc: if you order others to handle your data they must have access to these data. If you order someone to forward your mail they must have access to the mail, otherwise they cannot forward it. And if they have access they could read what's inside the mail. If you don't want this you have to make sure that they don't understand the contents of the mail even if they can read it, that means you have to encrypt the mail end-to-end. The issue is not much different from a post card sent snail mail - the post could read it because they need to handle it.

Comment: @voskyc: you could setup the domain for the client so that the mail gets sent directly to the mail servers of the client where you don't have access. But, since you are asked with managing the domain you can also set it up so that your own mail servers get used and then you have access. That means you can misuse the trust the client has in you. But you probably get into trouble if somebody notice that you read the mail because there are usually laws against it.